# Add email to GitHub commit in Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github

I am working on a project in Android Studio and collaborating using GitHub. Everything works fine except that my contributions are not credited to me in GitHub. I think this is because my email is not setup in android studio.

How can I add my email in Android Studio or if that is not the problem how can I get my commits to show up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the terminal try:
`$ git config --global user.name "YOUR USER NAME HERE"`
`$ git config --global user.email youremail@youremail.com`